# Understanding "Real world modelling" program

Tags: c++, algorithm, model

Few days now I've got new project to do related with a *"real world modelling"* program. 
Here's how it looks like:

> A visit to a psychologist (Use queue). Experts provides psychologist's advice, some of them (n) forms therapeutic groups of k people (GrT - duration of group therapy in hours), other experts (m) takes individual patients (InT - duration of individual therapy in hours). Each newly came patient (new patient's appearance probability is p1, recurring patients comes after period of time (h)) can choose to go to a psychologist providing individual therapies, or to group therapies. If group therapy session is full, patients who are wishing to participate in group sessions must wait. Recurring patients wishing to go to group sessions can start a session with smaller group, but can't go to same session with newly came patients. It has been observed that patients who took individual therapy are recovering faster than those, who chose group sessions(they will need less sessions), but there are exceptions - due to social interaction factor, some patients (probability p2) recover h percent faster than those, who choose individual therapy. Individual session costs InC, group session GrC. You need to assess what therapeutic approach patient should choose optimizing with their resources, and how many and what specialists should hire a health care facility.

Here's my approach to this problem:

- Read text file containing Names, Surnames, money willing to spend and place everything in queue structure.
- Find which group is better for patient by generating random number for `p2`probability and using it, we'll find if patient recover faster in individual or group therapy. IMO factor sequence here: `Money(looking, if patient can afford individual therapy sessions)` > `p2 (should patient take group sessions if it's better for him)`.
- By looking how many patients there are in queue, we can find how many psychologists we'll need. (Are there any other factors here? What if we are short of experts?)

Problems that I can't understand: how do I implement `p1` probability of new patients appearance if I write every patient into a text file and put them in a queue? How many therapy sessions does it take for patient to recover (static number?)?

Am I missing something? Basically it's open question and there could be no right answer. If anyone have any suggestions how to build this program to better one, I'd be glad to take it!

Programming language I'm using: C++

Answer (score 1):

If you want to break up a task, analyse it and prepare it for coding, you could :

1. Firstly make a [Block diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_diagram), representing program [flow control](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/).
2. Followed by [Pseudo code implementation](http://www.unf.edu/~broggio/cop3530/3530pseu.htm).

P.S. update the question following the above and when you reach the *"code stage"*, there, definitely, will be more help.

Comment: Thank you :). I'm currently doing that.